# How to add Swagger show action with rswag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swagger

I am trying to create a show action with the [rswag](https://github.com/rswag/rswag) gem in my RoR application for my api documentation. I am having trouble executing the documentation dynamically after I run `rake rswag:specs:swaggerize`. My problem is that since I cannot get the `id` or in my case the `slug` of my model object, I can't enter it simply by going in the docs. Here is an example from the github documentation.

```
path '/blogs/{id}' do

get 'Retrieves a blog' do
  tags 'Blogs'
  produces 'application/json', 'application/xml'
  parameter name: :id, in: :path, type: :string

  response '200', 'blog found' do
    schema type: :object,
      properties: {
        id: { type: :integer },
        title: { type: :string },
        content: { type: :string }
      },
      required: [ 'id', 'title', 'content' ]

    let(:id) { Blog.create(title: 'foo', content: 'bar').id }
    run_test!
  end
```

The example above is straight forward, we are creating a `Blog` instance and passing that id into the parameter path. However, when I see the html generated and try to pass in an id/slug for my case, I always get a 404 error because it cannot find the id.

Below is a picture of my swagger documentation.

[image]

As you can see in the picture, I can't enter a valid slug because I don't know it. I need to know the url slug before hand in order for it to work. So my question is how do I get around that. And finally, here is my code, which contains an index action and a show action. BTW my api does not support post create actions.

```
describe 'Companies API' do

  path '/api/v1/ipo-index' do

    get 'Retrieves an index of ipo company listings' do
      tags 'Companies'
      consumes 'application/json'
      produces 'application/json'

      response '200', 'ok' do
        let(:companies) do
          3.times do
            create(:company)
          end
        end
        run_test!
      end
    end
  end

  path '/api/v1/ipo/companies/{slug}' do
    get 'Retrieves a specific company listing' do
      tags 'Companies'
      consumes 'application/json'
      produces 'application/json'
      parameter name: :slug, in: :path, type: :string, description: 'Company url slug'

      let(:company) do
        create(:company)
      end

      response '200', 'Company found' do
        let(:slug) { company.slug  }  #### What is the slug?
        run_test!
      end

      response '404', 'Record not found' do
        let(:slug) { 'invalid-slug' }
        run_test!
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I am new to swagger documentation so any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Swagger's `try it out` feature makes real requests to the server you declared in `swagger_helper`. It has to know slug name to make a proper request, and it has to be a record existing in declared server db.